# GWT unit test case

Tags: gwt, gwttestcase

I was planning to write a unit test case for one of my helper methods in GWT.

Am getting error saying that **ERROR: GWT.create() is only usable in client code!  It cannot be called, for example, from server code.  If you are running a unit test, check that your test case extends GWTTestCase and that GWT.create() is not called from within an initializer or constructor.**

When I debug, I see that error is originating from the line

`NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyFormat();` in my code. Kindly help.

This is my code :

TestCase:

```
public class CurrencyFormatterTest extends GWTTestCase {

    private CurrencyFormatter currencyFormatter = new CurrencyFormatter();

    public void testCurrencyFormatForActualCurrencyString() {
        String formattedString = currencyFormatter.format( " 123456.78999" );
        assertEquals( "US$123,456.79", formattedString );
    }

@Override
    public String getModuleName() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Code to be Tested

```
public class CurrencyFormatter implements Formatter {

    @Override
    public String format( Object value ) {
        if ( value == null || value.equals( "" ) ) {
            return "";
        }
        Double val = Double.parseDouble( value.toString() );
        NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyFormat();
        String formattedValue = formatter.format( val );
        return formattedValue;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `getModuleName` returns `null` then your test runs just like any other JUnit test, i.e. **not** in a *GWT context*.

Make `getModuleName` return the name of your module (the one you pass to the GWT Compiler, or the one you'll `<inherit>` in another GWT module) to switch to running *as GWT*.

Comment: I did the same. I see that execution of the text case takes really long time (like some 4 to 5 secs). Any specific reasons?

Comment: [`GWTTestCase` is the reason](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideTesting.html): it launches a web server and a DevMode session with an HtmlUnit "browser emulation". Also have a look at [gwt-mockito](https://github.com/google/gwtmockito), [gwt-test-utils](https://github.com/gwt-test-utils/gwt-test-utils) and the GWTMockUtilities class from the GWT SDK.